# Square chunk my matrix

Tags: code-golf, matrix, set-partitions, statistics

Your challenge is to write a function/program that takes a matrix of integers m and a number n as input and:

- Splits m into n by n chunks
- Replaces each chunk with the most common value in that chunk (In case of a tie, any of the tied values is fine).
- Outputs the resulting matrix.

Note: You can take either the size of a single chunk, *or* the number of chunks to a side.

Example:

```
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1, 
2
```

Divide into chunks:

```
0 1|0 1
0 0|1 1
---+---
0 0|0 0
0 0|1 1
```

Take the most common value in each sub-matrix

```
0|1
-+-
0|0
```

So

```
0 1
0 0
```

is the result!

Note: You can assume that there will always be an integer amount of chunks with integer size.

Input will always be square.

## Testcases

These are formatted as taking the size of a single chunk.

```
0 1 2 1 2 1
2 2 1 0 2 2
2 1 2 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 3 2
3 0 2 0 3 1
1 0 3 2 0 1, 
3 =>
2 1
0 0
(The 1 is a tie, any of 012 are fine)

0 1 2 1 2 1
2 2 1 0 2 2
2 1 2 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 3 2
3 0 2 0 3 1
1 0 3 2 0 1, 
2 =>
2 1 2
0 0 3
0 2 1
(The 3 is a tie, any of 0123 are fine)

1,
1 => 
1
(kinda obvious edgecase)
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: Can we take the matrix transposed?

Comment: How does that help? It's the same thing...

Comment: I can remove the leading `Z` (transpose) from my answer if so

Comment: I'm gonna say no to that one.

Comment: Is the matrix guaranteed to be square?

Comment: Can we take the width and height of the matrix as input too

Comment: "You can take either the size of a single chunk, or the number of chunks to a side." but can we take both?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, it is.

Comment: @Adám One or the other.

Comment: @StackMeter Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
thZCtvXM[]e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQjyrmkLMI3Ojb1/38jrmgDBUMFILYGEiAmlAGEcJFYAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8kI8q5pCzCNzo29b@6rq56hEvIf2OuaAMFQwUjCLYGEiCmAYi2hoqC5A2sgRSYoWAMkjEGKwFxgHqgoiD5WC4jahtoyBVtGAsA).

#### How it works

```
th     % Implicit input: number n. Horizontally concatenate with itself to give [n n]
ZC     % Implicit input: matrix m. Im2col: arrange each [n n] block as a column of
       % length n*n
tv     % Vertically concatenate with itself. This makes columns twice as long without
       % affecting their mode. This is needed in case the previous result had a single
       % row (n=1), which would cause the subsequent mode function to compute the mode
       % of that row, instead of the mode of each column
XM     % Mode. This gives the mode of each column (the input has at least 2 rows)
[]e    % Reshape as a square matrix. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit infix function taking chunk size as left argument and the input matrix as right argument.

```apl
{(∪⊃⍨∘⊃∘⍒⊢∘≢⌸)∘,¨↑(⊂⊂¨⊂[1]∘⍵)(≢⍵)⍴⍺↑1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUceqR13Nj3pXPOqYAWIAyd5Jj7oWgRidix717NAEsnQOrXjUNlHjUVcTEAHZXU3RhrFgpVs1NUDKgPSj3i2PencBlRnW/k971DbhUW8f2OA1QIlD642BEo/6pgYHOQPJEA/P4P9GCmkKEEGvYH8/9ehoAx1DHSCO1QGyQGwYCwiRxGLVuXR1dbmMsek2gmCgaiMw2wBIGoF5IHGw@XCTDHSMwXLGYFUgHkgfVBzsDqhNRnSzyRDdJpAMAA)

`{`…`}` [dfn](https://apl.wiki/dfn); `⍺` is chunk size and `⍵` is matrix:
  `2` and
  `⎡0,1,0,1⎤`
  `⎢0,0,1,1⎥`
  `⎢0,0,0,0⎥`
  `⎣0,0,1,1⎦`

`⍺↑1` take "chunk size" elements from 1, padding with zeros
   `[1,0]`

`(≢⍵)⍴` cyclically reshape that to the number of rows in the matrix
   `[1,0,1,0]`

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit prefix function:

`⊂[1]∘⍵` use the argument to partition the matrix vertically
     `⎡0,1,0,1⎤ ⎡0,0,0,0⎤` 
    `[⎣0,0,1,1⎦,⎣0,0,1,1⎦]`

`⊂⊂¨` use the entire argument to partition each of those horizontally
      `⎡0,1⎤ ⎡0,1⎤   ⎡0,0⎤ ⎡0,0⎤`  
    `[[⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦],[⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦]]`

`↑` mix into a matrix
   `⎡ ⎡0,1⎤ ⎡0,1⎤ ⎤`
   `⎢ ⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎥`
   `⎢ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎥`
   `⎣ ⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎦`

`(`…`)∘,¨` for each element, ravel (flatten) it and then apply the following tacit prefix function:
   `⎡ [0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1] ⎤`
   `⎣ [0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1] ⎦`

`⊢∘≢⌸` for each unique element, count the indices it occurs at
    `⎡ [3,1],[1,3] ⎤`
    `⎣ [4]  ,[2,2] ⎦`

`∪`… with the unique elements…
    `⎡ [0,1],[0,1] ⎤`
    `⎣ [0]  ,[0,1] ⎦`

`∘⊃∘⍒` get the index of the largest count (lit. first element of the permutation vector that would sort the counts descending), then…
     `⎡1,2⎤`
     `⎣1,1⎦`

`⊃⍨` use that to pick from the list of unique elements
     `⎡0,1⎤`
     `⎣0,0⎦`

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
(0{~.\:1#.=)@,;.3~2 2&$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU3BCsIwDL3nKx5T3Ao1tOmtZTAQPHnyLHgQN/HiBwj79Zp1xYMHCUle3iPvPXPD7Yg@ooWFQ9TeMw7n0zF37j3zJfoN92awicMskN02G5r6eL89XkOX0jgbWjAEExpOfBV0xceQg1c7r3tB69b63v8/ZW2SgpxOoZUrvtXFISgfir5gT5UryTXBa4KNPxmq5g8)

J's `u;.3` is pretty handy for this. It splits a matrix into rectangles. You just need to give the size of the rectangles and the offset between rectangles. So for `3x3`-tiles the input would be `[[3 3],[3 3]]`. That is handled by `2 2&$` (if we can take width and height of a tile as input, that would be `;.~` for -2 bytes). For each tile `;.3~` we flatten the tile `,` and sort `\:` the unique values `~.` by their occurences `1#.=` and take the first one `0{`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
2Æ=yòV)ËËc ü ñÊÌÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=MsY9efJWKcvLYyD8IPHKzMw&input=WwpbMCAxIDIgMSAyIDFdClsyIDIgMSAwIDIgMl0KWzIgMSAyIDAgMSAwXQpbMCAwIDEgMCAzIDJdClszIDAgMiAwIDMgMV0KWzEgMCAzIDIgMCAxXQpdCjIKLVE)

```
2Æ=yòV)ËËc ü ñÊÌÌ     :Implicit input of 2D-array U and integer V
2Æ                    :Map the range [0,2)
  =                   :Reassign to U
   y                  :  Transpose
    òV                :  Partition rows to length V
      )               :End reassignment
       Ë              :Map
        Ë             :  Map
         c            :    Flatten
           ü          :    Group & sort by value
             ñ        :    Sort by
              Ê       :      Length
               Ì      :    Last element
                Ì     :    Last element
                      :Implicit output of last element in the range
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Zs€Zs€ẎF€ÆṃḢ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@q@FHTGjDxcFefG5A63PZwZ/PDHYuAzP8Pd295uGMTkBUGxCC55Ye2Fvscbju0V8X9/38DBUMFIwjmMgKzDICkERdEDCRrwGUAoRWMgeLGYHkQ25ALKgaS/W8EAA)

### How it works

```
Zs€Zs€ẎF€ÆṃḢ€ - Main link. Takes M on the left and n on the right
Z             - Transpose M
 s€           - Slice each row into n pieces
   Z          - Transpose
    s€        - Split each group of columns into n pieces
      Ẏ       - Flatten into a list of n x n matrices
       F€     - Flatten each matrix
         ÆṃḢ€ - Get the first mode of each
```

Comment: when the footer is longer than the 13 byte answer

Comment: [These](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Krfhw28OdzQ93LHrUtIar@PByIHVoU@3/w8v1gSx3IM561LiPi@v//@joaAMdBUMdBSM4GaujEG0EEzAAM4ygYhAVEA0GIDEDOE9HwRiqzhimCyIGNg@hAqIhFihoDJIYOOuNINaD2YaxAA) [are](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/784yq345PRHTWsObao93PZwZ/PDHYuAPCD6f3i5PpByB@KsR437uLj@/4@OjjbQUTDUUTCCk7E6CtFGMAEDMMMIKgZRAdFgABIzgPN0FIyh6oxhuiBiYPMQKiAaYoGCxiCJgbPeCGI9mG0YCwA) also 13 bytes, if you can think of anywhere to go with them

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
sZ€FÆṃḢƊ⁹ÐƤ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7846lHTGrfDbQ93Nj/csehY16PGnYcnHFsCFPx/eLm@u2bWo8Z9h7Yd2vb/fzRXdHS0gY6CoY4CiIzVUQDxIAJIPBBCk4vVMYrVQeg2gpMgdUYwAQMwwwgqBlEBtQ7FPCBpDFVnDNMFEQObh1ABdWesjvGA2g71O4hpGMsVCwA)

After several 13s, I found a 12. A dyadic link taking the grid as a list of lists of integers on the left side and the size of the split on the right.

### Explanation

```
s            | Split into sublists of the length specified by the right argument
 Z€          | Transpose each
       Ɗ⁹ÐƤ€ | For each sublist, do the following for each non-overlapping infix of the length specified by the original right argument:
   F         | - Flatten
    Æṃ       | - Mode
      Ḣ      | - Head
```

Comment: The 12 I found is similar, [`s⁹ZsFÆṃḢƊ€ɗ€`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/4UePOqGK3w20PdzY/3LHoWNejpjUnpwOJ/w93b3m4YxOQFQbEQHR4ufv//wYKhgpGEMxlBGYZAEkjLogYSNaQywBMGygYKxhzGYPlQWxDLogYWNV/IwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>130</s> <s>124</s> <s>121</s> <s>116</s> 111 bytes

*-5 bytes and another 3 thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```r
function(M,n,k=dim(M))array(Map(function(x)el(names(sort(-table(x))):0),split(M,t(a<-(row(M)-1)%/%n)*k+a)),k/n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/dDoIwDIXv9x4mrZa4QeKFkUfgzntTESOBDR0jwtNjwZ8YTbN0@057uvqxvXXsi0N@6VyVjufO5aFsHGTkqEpPpYUMkb3nATK@wkfvsajBsS1aaBsfIAp8rAvBiFuN1F7rMohJAN5F4Ju72EQGF@uFw2W1YkSq1g5Hm1oOvuwhB02G4tdR8Zw0TVk9qZ6B0q9LMinJXDI9pOdNRUfaSBwHGZzuUanvJcFSgr8k/iPmlzz/aWSS2BscHw)

Longer approach than [@Dominic's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229841/55372), but I thought it's worth a try.

Builds matrix mask `t(a<-(row(M)-1)%/%n)*dim(M)+a` used then in `split`, for example for matrix \$6\times6\$ and \$n=2\$:

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    6    6   12   12
[2,]    0    0    6    6   12   12
[3,]    1    1    7    7   13   13
[4,]    1    1    7    7   13   13
[5,]    2    2    8    8   14   14
[6,]    2    2    8    8   14   14
```

Comment: This may be a bit longer, but I'm glad you posted it: I tried for ages to get a ```split``` approach to work, without success.  This is very neat.

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/BDoIwDIbvew@SVkcYkHgw8gjcvJuyzEhkA7cR8ennQDRG0zRtv79NWxvcbSSrTvIymmsVzqORvu0N1NygJm/bCWoa4MMnVB0Y0sqB662H1FPTqYgR9wK5G7rWx2FNE9AhBdvfocY0xyRLzDbHjQfCLSFyI/suSpnBoKt1kwTBc16szoolCD5H9qJiAUysSTkr5dIyF3HmTaOOfBetecQbqiMy9v0paF7iLyn@SI7hCQ) with a bit of cleaning...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, thanks, I always forget about `Map`...

Comment: ...and another [-3](https://tio.run/##ZY/BDoIwDIbvew@SVkcYkHgw8gjcvJuCMxLZwG1EePo5QI3RNE3/fn@bpsbb@0BGnurroG@Fvwy6dk2noeQayRiaoKQePnhE2YImJS3YzjiIHVWtDBhxL5Dbvm1c2HVAhxhM94AS4xSjJNK40Wu/JUR@blSQiUavCkXONCPUIHjKs1eybCmCz5WtVCyAiZfIZydfRuYm7Lxp8JHvQlRTuFkckbHvN0HxHH9J9kdS9E8)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, that's nice golf for the mask matrix, thanks! I managed to shave off another two by replacing `nrow` with `dim` and further optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
BlockMap[Commonest[Join@@#,1]&,#2,{#,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY5BCsIwEEX3PUUh0NWAabIWguJGEASXpYsQWlo0iWh2Ib16nKSt1AvIMANv/s/8aOmGTks3Khn7fTw8rLpf5LM5Wq2t6d6uOdvRCEGgbisgDDwBEtoqXl@jcTvRC3FSgxWkmm5KmskXnkFRek@hBuyAUCIk3ADWrxIQPf@@ZHPPHpaR4mTrIqk5YXuFAl8dPNvTYrmxqPlLOYv9MavOWQmKED8)

Input `[n, m]`. Returns a matrix of singleton lists.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

-1 byte from @Traws

```
{(*>#'=,/)''2(+(0N;y)#/:)/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJytkE0KwjAQhfc5xaNdNNFA87Nr0CN4AXFRtEVBk9JWtIie3SStIIo7EzLz3gxkPqYubnS2TLMFz1mWKTqnYmUGluYFy693QqiANAKCPep10Ji8V2P29+WZURtCcsiuR+suHMrusHXH88liX3ZIZALaVC0a1/UcpR3gagipULYV6oOtGKHqY54an1FRCR+VGWuRZpotoH1dx37Q0ky10GVGR66AE7l0+8V1sGiO5bYKRIn+wak/QP1IMS3Eu/8ih1VSzuOvPhnp/dt5Aj33X88=)

Based off of @Shaggy's [Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229833/98547). Takes the input matrix as `x` and the chunk size as `y`.

- `2(...)/x` set up a do-reduce, seeded with `x` and run twice

  - `(+(0N;y)#/:)` slice each row into `y`-length chunks, then transpose them
- `(...)''` run the code in `(...)` on each chunk in the transformed matrix

  - `(*>#'=,/)` group the flattened chunk contents, counting the number of times each distinct number appears, then sort descending and return the first value (i.e. the mode)

Comment: I guess you could transpose after the slice, saving 1 byte

Comment: Thanks, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 37 ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit infix function taking chunk count as right argument and the input matrix as right argument.

```apl
((∪⊃⍨∘⊃∘⍒⊢∘≢⌸)∘,⍤2)1 3 2 4⍉⊣⍴⍨4⍴⊢,≢⍛÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X0PjUceqR13Nj3pXPOqYAWIAyd5Jj7oWgRidix717NAEsnQe9S4x0jRUMFYwUjB51Nv5qGvxo94tQE0mIKprkQ5Iae/sw9v/pz1qm/Cotw9s5Bqg5KH1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g/8bKaQBtSpAxL2C/f3Uo6MNdAx1gDhWB8gCsWEsIEQSi1Xn0tXV5cJlgBEEAzUYgdkGQNIIzAOJg62AG2agYwyWMwarAvFA@qDiYKdALTOmp2WGWCwDSQIA)

`{`…`}` [dfn](https://apl.wiki/dfn); `⍺` is matrix and `⍵` is chunk size:
  `⎡0,1,0,1⎤`
  `⎢0,0,1,1⎥`
  `⎢0,0,0,0⎥`
  `⎣0,0,1,1⎦`
  and `2`

`≢⍛÷` the matrix size divided by the chunk size
   `2`

`⊢,` prepend the matrix size 
   `[2,2]`

`4⍴` cyclically reshape to size 4
   `[2,2,2,2]`

`⊣⍴⍨` use that to reshape the matrix
   `⎡ ⎡0,1⎤ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎤`
   `⎢ ⎣0,1⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎥`
   `⎢ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎥`
   `⎣ ⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎦`

`1 3 2 4⍉` switch the middle two axes
   `⎡ ⎡0,1⎤ ⎡0,1⎤ ⎤`
   `⎢ ⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎥`
   `⎢ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎡0,0⎤ ⎥`
   `⎣ ⎣0,0⎦,⎣1,1⎦ ⎦`

`(`…`)∘,⍤2` on each 2D leaf, ravel (flatten) it and then apply the following tacit prefix function:
   `⎡ [0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1] ⎤`
   `⎣ [0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1] ⎦`

`⊢∘≢⌸` for each unique element, count the indices it occurs at
    `⎡ [3,1],[1,3] ⎤`
    `⎣ [4]  ,[2,2] ⎦`

`∪`… with the unique elements…
    `⎡ [0,1],[0,1] ⎤`
    `⎣ [0]  ,[0,1] ⎦`

`∘⊃∘⍒` get the index of the largest count (lit. first element of the permutation vector that would sort the counts descending), then…
     `⎡1,2⎤`
     `⎣1,1⎦`

`⊃⍨` use that to pick from the list of unique elements
     `⎡0,1⎤`
     `⎣0,0⎦`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>136</s>  135 bytes

Expects `(matrix)(chunk_size)`.

```javascript
m=>n=>m.slice(-m.length/n).map((_,y,a)=>a.map((_,x)=>eval("for(o=K={},i=n*n;i--;)(o[v=m[y*n+i/n|0][x*n+i%n]]=-~o[v])<K?0:K=o[V=v];V")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY9Bb8IgHMXvfArSZBHUIqu3dXSn7WKyi4mX2iysUmUpfzpaG41zX72j7cy@wA7Ae7/3IPw/ZCvr3OmqCcHuVFeIzogERGJYXepckdCwUsG@OSyAMiMrQt7m57mkIpE3e/JGtbIkQWEdsWIlLte5FjCFWIdhTIlNW2HS8xRmegFfPEtPvbyDLBPhtw8z@rh64g8rYdONaLN4E1BKO6c@j9opMinqCWVOyd2LLtX6DDnhlDV23TgNe0JZXZW6IcEWthBQ5v/wLPMDqbFI8AVhLLHA9V8poLGH4OFMsspWZPDG@3Eg199ztz4Oxqlfj@ZdOTp0cwu1LRUr7Z4UxFACPb/SjuN7HI0LRYPifo/QyPqUIz6eeOn5csh7fY9@WZ@iJUL/9VSEkAc/)

#### Commented

This is a version without `eval()` for readability.

```javascript
m => n =>                     // m[] = matrix; n = chunk size
m.slice(-m.length / n)        // get an array of m.length / n entries
.map((_, y, a) =>             // for each value at position y in this slice:
  a.map((_, x) => {           //   for each value at position x in this slice:
    for(                      //     chunk loop:
      o =                     //       o is used to store all counts
      K = {},                 //       K is used to store the highest count
      i = n * n;              //       start with i = n * n
      i--;                    //       stop when i = 0 / decrement it
    ) ( o[                    //
          v = m[              //       v is the value in m[]
            y * n + i / n | 0 //       at row y * n + floor(i / n)
          ][                  //       and column x * n + (i mod n)
            x * n + i % n     //
          ]                   //
        ] = -~o[v]            //       increment o[v]
      ) < K ? 0               //       do nothing if it's less than K
            : K = o[V = v];   //       otherwise update V to v and K to o[v]
    return V                  //     implicit end of for(); return V
  })                          //   end of inner map()
)                             // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>113</s> <s>111</s> 108 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes, and then -3 more bytes, thanks to pajonk*

(or [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/bCsIwDIbv@ySJZthu4IW4txBvhkg3Kg5til2Hmy8/uzlFlJDT9yeQ@KG5tdqbY3Vu@ZIPp5arUDsGS4yuDcaD2yZyA@zdHSyuOFG4YHK0N1Vwvn4Y@Ox01CNraxponA@QBF1eDdiiW6oNUz/GA2KhYsDB5lYHX3dQgSRF6ewinZKkMYsXlRMQci6yUcmmkbGJO28adaR1tLKP5@Y7FOL7vfhUhr8k/SMKhyc) by outputting a matrix of text strings representing the integers)

```r
function(m,n)outer(o<-0:(nrow(m)/n-1)*n,o,Vectorize(function(x,y)el(names(sort(-table(m[x+1:n,y+1:n]))):0)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/bCsIwDIbv@ySJZthu4MVwbyHeiMg2Kg5til2Hmy9fuzlFlJDT9yeQuNDeutLpY33u@FKEU8e1byyDIUbbee3AbhKZAzt7B4MrThQumCztdO2tax4aPjs9DaivwKXRLbTWeUh8WV01mH2/VDnTMMYDIuYyhmAKU3rX9FCDJEXp7CKdkqQxixeVExByLrJRyaaRsYk7bxp1pHW0aogXF1sU4vvD@FeGvyT9IwrDEw)

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##ZY9tC4JADMff3yfZatKdQi8kv0X0RiRULpK6HZ0naV/eTrOIYuzp999gc2N760qnj/W540s2njqufWMZDDHazmsHdhfJFNjZOxjccKRwxWTpoGtvXfPQ8NnpaUB9BS6NbqG1zkPky@qqweT9WqVMwxQLxFwVmEpEHE1mSu@aHmqQpCheXMRzkjRl8aJyBkIuRTIpyTwyNWHnTYOOtA1WDeHobI9CfD8ZXkvwl8R/ROH4BA "R – Try It Online") with `el(.:0)` trick converting to integer.

Comment: Another [-3](https://tio.run/##ZY/bCsIwDIbv@ySJZthu4MVwbyHeiMg2Kg5til2Hmy9fuzlFlJDT9yeQuNDeutLpY33u@FKEU8e1byyDIUbbee3AbhKZAzt7B4MrThQumCztdO2tax4aPjs9DaivwKXRLbTWeUh8WV01mH2/VDnTMMYDIuYyhmAKU3rX9FCDJEXp7CKdkqQxixeVExByLrJRyaaRsYk7bxp1pHW0aogXF1sU4vvD@FeGvyT9IwrDEw "R – Try It Online") - we don't need to select the first element from `sort`, as `:` will do that for us (with a warning).

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks again, although I really should've noticed that myself...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 174 bytes

Quite long, very ugly, possibly the most comprehensions I've used in one statement. There is undoubtedly a better way to do this but I can't look at this thing anymore.

```
def f(m,n):l=len(m);r=range(0,l,n);b=l/n;print('%s '*b+'\n')*b%tuple(max(v,key=v.count)for v in[sum([x[k][j:j+n]for k in range(n)],[])for x in[m[i:i+n]for i in r]for j in r])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFLcoMwDN37FN5ksBO1JWYHw0kcLyA1LT/BgGHI6ak/NM0FOh55nvSeLEsaH@Z7QLHvn7qiFesBedrlnUbW82zKpwK/NIuhs/GszLsPzMapRsOi00yjc3mJbhjxc3kyy9hp1hcbW6HVj3x9vw8LGl4NE11pjXJeeiY32SrZpM0FlSNaS9BQArkCqbx8c/Je1ml9yGov87AJkO9Gz@ZezHqmOZWESRnDFawpIBY65wnteY0qAoLDb4oI5gTCO7G9RXAd45/9S48hCWzihc71uQfjf0AUJP9d4OjAdgNXThQhbjh2eW48z9GkhB7LeovOIg67IseWySvF9x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 96 bytes

Takes as input an integer matrix \$ m \$, and an integer \$ n \$ denoting the chunk size.

```python
lambda m,n:[[max(x:=sum(j,()),key=x.count)for j in zip(*[zip(*i)]*n)]for i in zip(*[iter(m)]*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY5NjoMwDIX3PoV3xAghCpsREicBFkwBTTqNiZJUgrk8daBqLzAL/73Pz7Ldws/C1Zd1@9x0@30w3@OAJuO6bc2wqrVu/MOoW6aIst9pa9b8ujw40Lw4vKFm/NNWpe2RNfUpUx@R/iAdJqfMiXZt7OIC@s1DXLsOfoqbMuc@jJpzNw2jIhmcmKXauw4q6bjjhGrA1GTI2BzGD0wI0IgqL1ulOWSoX5AI3@@YHg6vLCgWh3Wxm1U8SbQXeMHyDCiPrpBcwqlFWkBxVqxErw4e@wu8tEihAvivUyWACE8)

Very messy use of the [split into chunks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184881/88546) golfing tip.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2F¹δôø}εε˜.M
```

First input is chunk-size \$n\$, second input is matrix \$m\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyO3QznNbDm85vKP23NZzW0/P0fMFCnJFRxvoGOoYQXCsTrQRmG0AJI3APJA4SIUBkGcAYekYg@WMwapAPJA@qDhIRWwsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/ipuSZV1BaUmyloGTvEmqvpJCYlwJk2v43cos4t@XwlsM7as9tPbf19Bw93/@1tTqHttn/N@KKjjbQMdQB4lgdIAvEhrGAEEkslssYqtYIgoFyRmC2AZA0AvNA4mDT4PoMdIzBcsZgVSAeSB9UHGxrLJcRjcw1BJoLpAE).

**Explanation:**

```python
2F       # Loop two times:
   δ     #  Map over each row of the second (implicit) input-matrix:
  ¹ ô    #   Split it into parts equal to the first input-integer
     ø   #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
 }ε      # After the loop: map over each row of matrices:
   ε     #  Inner map over each matrix:
    ˜    #   Flatten this matrix to a list
     .M  #   Pop and only leave the most frequent integer in this list
         # (after which the mapped matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 159 bytes

```javascript
n=>k=>n.flatMap((e,i)=>i%k?[]:e.flatMap((h,j)=>j%k?[]:(M=n.slice(i,i+k).map(K=>K.slice(j,j+k)).flat()).sort((a,b)=>(X=Y=>M.map(Z=>z+=Z==Y,z=0)|z)(b)-X(a))[0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZBLboMwEIb3nMKbKjOKgwzsKo17gIiuk1CkmNS0BscgoF2g3p2aR9VFL9DFPPT9M6NfU6lP1d860w4H17zqqaTJkaxJurC0akhVC6C5QZLmoX7K8kf9y9955Xm1ckjJhb01Nw2Gm32N4d3PHEkeN1rxylNc1sHXvukGAMULfwNOdCaZLisXkuOeLkRnPpLArxGhwMMJFGImcsTp1ri@sTq0zRuUcBUsYvEaQbx0wuc4WNmsikCslSWeJ4s@91GwsVm9hn1rzQC7F7dbvWvLSDJtfwS28eePe6E7RIQEMfg/buI/brIsynOEyD/tGw)

Golfing languages which have built-ins for occurrence count or chunks have concise programs. Mine is 159 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 54 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪Ｅθ⪪ιηη«≔⟦⟧ζＦＬ§ι⁰«≔⟦⟧εＦι≔⁺ε§λκε≔Ｅε№ελδ⊞ζ§ε⌕δ⌈δ»⊞υζ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwDIbP9VPoaIMGXnrcqRQGgxUCO5ocTJ01Zq7TxfEoHX12z46SdBch//o@WcdOD8deu5Q@@wH4x8XZkR/0hX8j0MMidEJMBX7ZZheCPXmuGoSbeGGbSXtv/Wns@G5886a9FkUKwv/zbeFJsALmQe1i4C3C4jqEr/IdwTNUDsrMvo9@LI0rhJmIOoaO3x5@nr5ab7hBOOirPcczN/mWwt4Z0ZFOv7N6sHnfXoeRx0ykpJSSCM8I1VobZACqWiI5NdWaEkWSpFSub4Ttym4Xl9J574MiqWmKkJ5@3B8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪪Ｅθ⪪ιηη«
```

Split each column into chunks of size `n`, then split the rows into chunks of size `n` and loop over the chunks.

```
≔⟦⟧ζ
```

Start collecting the results for this chunk of rows.

```
ＦＬ§ι⁰«
```

Loop over the number of chunks of columns.

```
≔⟦⟧εＦι≔⁺ε§λκε
```

Collect all of the values in this chunk of matrix into a single array.

```
≔Ｅε№ελδ
```

Get the frequencies of all the values.

```
⊞ζ§ε⌕δ⌈δ
```

Collect the value with the greatest frequency (chooses the first such value in case of a tie).

```
»⊞υζ
```

Save the results for this chunk of rows.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output all of the results using Charcoal's default array output format.